# Updating checkbox value within CheckBox1_Click event runs code twice

Tags: excel, vba

I  want the checkbox stays the same and generates a message box.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Dim beast As String

beast = Range("k1").Value

If beast = "No" Then
    CheckBox1 = False
    MsgBox "You Are Missing Ingredients", vbCritical, "Missing Ingredients"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You're changing the CheckBox1 value in the code, which causes the Click to fire again. Don't do that. In the future, you can solve this sort of problem yourself by using the debugger to step through the code.

Comment: But that's the point of that code. I want the checkbox to be unclickable if the value is no. How can i do that then?

Comment: The checkbox remains clickable with your code. I think you're looking for the `Enabled` property if you're wanting it to not be clickable. If your goal is to change its value always to false, then do it somewhere other than the Click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable application events. Application events for ActiveX controls are trapped by the code sheet belonging to the worksheet on which the control has been installed. Therefore the code below must be on that code sheet, not a standard code module where it will never run.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Dim beast   As String
    
    With CheckBox1
        If .Value = True Then
            beast = Range("K1").Value
            If beast = "No" Then
                MsgBox "You Are Missing Ingredients", vbCritical, "Missing Ingredients"
                ' prevent the upcoming change from triggering this event
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = False
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Make sure that your check box is an ActiveX control. In fact, once you create such a control it will be listed in the controls drop-down on the top left of the sheet's code module and VBA will create or select the click event procedure for you.

I have tested the above code and it doesn't run more thna once on one click. I have added a check to let it do nothing if the checkmark was removed rather than set.

Comment: Where is your checkbox (worksheet or user form)? Where is your code (standard or worksheet module)?

Comment: I have checked, revised and tested the code. Please make sure you install it on the sheet's code sheet, not a standard code module, and that your check box is an ActiveX control.

Comment: You are right. Thank you so much. It works perfectly

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work correctly. Thank you for the feedback. Please remember to select the answer.

Comment: So I used the code for a couple of my checkboxes, but it is giving me the msgbox in some boxes that are true and putting them back in true.

Comment: The code runs when a checkbox is clicked. The checkbox is identified by the procedure's name as well as in the code itself, twice in each procedure. The only way to get another checkbox affected is if that other checkbox's name is mentioned in the code. To be clear, each checkbox must have its own event procedure. Add a line to the code like `Debug.Print "Checkbox1_Click"` to create visible a record of which procedure ran on which of your clicks.

Comment: debugging is showing the code is going through the correct steps, but the code isn't working in some checkboxes. I don't understand why

Comment: After playing for a while with the code I realized that the checkboxes that are having problems is because of the range  line I used, which I don't see anything wrong with it since the value of the range is TRUE, so the code is supposed to do nothing when the value is TRUE. This is the code line I used to assign value to the variable `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Checkbox Formulas").Range("E28").Value ` . With the other checkboxes it works fine, bu there are like 6 checkboxes out of the 120 checkboxes I use that gives me this problem.

Comment: Dealing with 120 checkboxes isn't the theme of this thread. Please formulate another question where you have room to explain the problem properly. As a matter of principle, I wouldn't place so many ActiveX controls on one worksheet. I would use an event procedure that places or removes a checkmark-like character from *Wingdings* on double-click. In another thread I would show you how to do it. Here, there is no room to either understand your problem or offer a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static boolean variable to avoid the double execution, like so:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Static isBusy As Boolean
    Dim beast As String

    If Not isBusy Then
        isBusy = True
        
        beast = Range("k1").Value
        If beast = "No" Then
            CheckBox1.Value = False
            MsgBox "You Are Missing Ingredients", vbCritical, "Missing Ingredients"
        End If
        
        isBusy = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Static variables maintain their values across invocations, so if you set it in the first CheckBox1_Click invocation, you can check it in the second one and know a first invocation is ongoing.

Comment: So I used the code for a couple of my checkboxes, but it is giving me the msgbox in some boxes that are true and putting them back in true.